# Two Tables - If age is less than, then do

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. One is named empdata the other is empinfo.

empdata (raw employee data) - age column has employees age.

empinfo (dev info side) - isUnderage is a BIT 0/1 true/false column.

I'm trying to create the following if statement to update the entire table: IF employee is under 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0.

Here is what I have so far and I get errors using MySql:

empdata (raw employee data) - has employee ids under a column named "FileNumber"

empinfo (dev info side) - has the same employee ids under a column called "empid"

```
UPDATE isUnderage
        isUnderage = CASE empdata.Age
         WHEN empdata.Age > 17 THEN 1
          ELSE 0
        END,
FROM empinfo
```

Comment: Go through the UPDATE syntax of mysql. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: what is the relationship between two table ? is there any unique id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update query will look something like this:

```
UPDATE empinfo t1
INNER JOIN empdata t2
ON t1.empid = t2.FileNumber 
SET t1.isUnderage = IF(t2.Age > 17, 1, 0);
```

Comment: Any ideas here?  The column is definitely there.    --ERROR:
#1054 - Unknown column 'empdata.Age' in 'field list'

Comment: Age is there in the empinfo table??

Comment: The employee 'Age' is listed in the empdata. 'isUnderage' is on the empinfo table

Comment: Ok..then how both tables are related? Wat is the foriegn key?? Show me the relation

Comment: I get you but I'm not sure what you are asking. These two are separate tables in the same database. empdata constantly gets changed and empinfo is just basic development side "isUnderage" etc. There is nothing "linked" between the two.

Comment: I've noticed there is nothing linking the second table "empdata" in any of the queries in your post.

Comment: Dude..Can u post the column names of both table in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use `UPDATE` with `JOIN` and a `CASE` expression.

**Query**

```
UPDATE empinfo t1
JOIN empdata t2
ON t1.empid = t2.FileNumber
SET t1.isUnderage = (
     CASE WHEN t2.Age < 17 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
);
```